как заменить начальные пробелы
как зациклить поиск с заменой в текстовом редакторе sublime3?
регуляркой '^ ' пытаюсь заменить все начальные пробелы во всех строках файла, но регулярка отрабатывает только один раз, как зациклить?

поиск: регулярные выражения квантификатор звёздочка

@aleksandrbarakin +
